# Discord.js code wont ban people. How do i fix this?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i have coded a little ban command here is the code

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ban`)) {

    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    member.ban().then((member) => {
        message.channel.send(`:wave: ${member.displayName} has been kicked`);
    }).catch(() => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
            message.reply("You cannot ban members");
        } else if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
            message.reply("You cannont ban this member");
        }
    })
}
```

And when i do my prefix ban and then the player name it does not ban them and i dont get any errors in the console so can i please have some help

Thnaks

Robin

Comment: Are you using the user's **name** or mention?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (message) => {
    let args = message.content.split(' ');
    let command = args.shift();
    if (command === 'ban') {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
        if (!member) return message.reply('pls mention a member or write ID for BAN');
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('You has no permission for ban members');
        if (message.member.roles.highest <= member.roles.highest) return message.reply(`You can't ban member with the same or highest role position`);
        if (!member.manageable) return message.reply('I cant ban this member');
        member.ban();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the resopse! i indeed had const discord = requrie('discord.js); and i do have const client = new discord.client(); Edit: i have changed the code to this and it still does not ban that person and does not leave any errors in the console @Cipher

Comment: This has not worked it does not leave any error in the console and it does not say in the chat that it cant ban the person

Comment: Try add `.catch(err => console.log(err))` after `member.ban()`

Answer (score 0):

my answer was the

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    let args = message.content.split(' ');
    let command = args.shift();
    if (command === 'ban') {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
        if (!member) return message.reply('pls mention a member or write ID for BAN');
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('You has no permission for ban members');
        if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= member.roles.highest.position) return message.reply(`You can't ban member with the same or highest role position`);
        if (!member.manageable) return message.reply('I cant ban this member');
        member.ban();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work:

```
if (message.content.startsWith('+ban')){
  const user2 = message.mentions.users.first();
  // If we have a user mentioned
  if (user2) {
    // Now we get the member from the user
    const member = message.guild.member(user2);
    const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription("*You don't have permission to use this command*")
  .setColor(0xffe6f7)

  if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(banembed)
    // If the member is in the guild
    if (member) {
      /**
       * Ban the member
       * Make sure you run this on a member, not a user!
       * There are big differences between a user and a member
       */
      member
        .ban('Being bad') //This is the reason
        .then(() => {
          // We let the message author know we were able to kick the person
          const bannedembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`***Successfully banned ${user2.tag}***`)
          .setColor(0xffe6f7)
            message.channel.send(bannedembed)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // An error happened
          // This is generally due to the bot not being able to kick the member,
          // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
          message.reply('I was unable to ban the member');
          // Log the error
          console.error(err);
        });
    } else {
      // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
      const nomemembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription("*That user isn't in this server!*")
  .setColor(0xffe6f7)
    message.channel.send(nomemembed)
    }
    // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
  } else {
      const nobanmentionembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription("*You didn't mention the user*")
  .setColor(0xffe6f7)                                      //you can remove the color if you want
    message.channel.send(nobanmentionembed)
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you want to kick, copy and paste everything and change `.ban()` to `.kick` and `.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")` to `.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")`